# Play! app reloads on change in coffeescript

Tags: playframework, coffeescript, playframework-2.3

I recently switched to PlayFramework 2.3. My application uses CoffeeScript, added by sbt plugin. When my app is running (via 'activator run'), if I touch any of my coffee files and press F5 in browser, then the whole application reloads:

```
[info] Done updating.

---  Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to C:\Users\myuserlogin\Work\myappname\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[info] CoffeeScript compiling on 1 source(s)
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[info] CoffeeScript compiling on 1 source(s)

--- (RELOAD) ---

[info] play - Application started (Dev)
```

Is there a way to NOT reload whole application, like it was in PlayFramework 2.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in 2.3 - https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3105.

It has been fixed and hopefully it'll be released as part of 2.3.2, which will hopefully come out [this week](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/kz3iaBbPIwA/5xAK8boOpJkJ).

Also see this [still open] issue, if you're running into that as well: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2905

Comment: Thanks, I surely will look forward to see this (hopefully) in the end of this week.

Comment: Yesterday, Play 2.3.2-RC1 was released. This problem is fixed.